# How to nest a json column in another one in bigquery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a string column in bigquery with json format, let's call it `child_col` and as en example it has the value `'{"code": "foo"}'`.
I'm trying to create another string column, e.g. `parent_col`, with a json value that has the json in `child_cold` as a nested property, e.g.

```
'{
  "code": "parent",
  "child": {"code": "foo"}
}'
```

I am doing it by using `TO_JSON_STRING` in Bigquery:

```
parent_col = TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT('parent' AS code, child_col AS child))
```

This almost works but looks at `child_col` as a plain string and the result looks like this:

```
'{
  "code": "parent",
  "child": "{\"code\": \"foo\"}"
}'
```

I've tried nesting the `child_col` in `TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT('parent' AS code, child_col AS child))` in `JSON_VALUE()`, `JSON_QUERY(child_col, '$')`, `JSON_EXTRACT(child_col, '$')`, the first one gives a json `null` always and the latter two are still escaping things. e.g.

```
parent_col = TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT('parent' AS code, JSON_QUERY(child_col, '$') AS child))
```

What's an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your input was treated as a string by `STRUCT()` so the value of `child` is a whole string `"{"code": "foo"}"`. As per [BigQuery JSON encodings](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_encodings), when using JSON functions, strings inside the struct specifically **double quotes (")**, **backslash (\)** and **control characters** are automatically escaped. So it is expected that `"` were escaped using your example.

> Invalid UTF-8 field names might result in unparseable JSON. String
> values are escaped according to the JSON standard. Specifically, ", ,
> and the control characters from U+0000 to U+001F are escaped.

While this is not the best solution, a possible workaround is to replace the backslash(\) and the double quotes (") beside the curly brackets to make it a valid json string.

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT '{ "code": "foo" }' AS child_col 
),
CTE_2 AS (
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT('parent' AS code, child_col AS child)) as json_val 
from CTE
)

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(json_val,'\\"','\"'),'\"{','{'),'}\"','}') as fixed_json 
FROM CTE_2
```

Output (See `fixed_json` field) :

[image]

Comment: @user2268997 let me know if my answer was helpful or not, so I can update/delete it.

Comment: It's a good approach. I was looking for something that does not need string processing. Don't you think it is a bug that the child is escaped when it is passed to `JSON_EXTRACT` or `JSON_QUERY` in the `STRUCT` constructor? - I expect it would result in a nested `STRUCT` and `TO_JSON_STRING` shouldn't escape anything.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear what I mean